# why style.format from pandas doesn't work in spyder?

Tags: python, pandas, spyder

maybe I missing something, I have this:

```
import pandas as pd

series1 = pd.Series({'DEPOSITOS': 353254})
series2 = pd.Series({'DEPOSITOS': 54464.43})
series3 = pd.Series({'COLOCACIONES': 6381763761})
series4 = pd.Series({'COLOCACIONES': 687513761})
series5 = pd.Series({'%PROV': 0.95})
series6 = pd.Series({'%PROV': 0.25})

top100v3 = pd.DataFrame([series1, series2, series3,series4, series5, series6])

top100v3.style.format({"DEPOSITOS": "{:,.0f}"})
```

but when I run it it doesn't change the dataframe (top100v3), and it just return:

C:\Users\yvs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py:253: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  res_values = method(rvalues)
Out[1]:

Comment: Does it work in another coding environment (e.g. jupyter notebook)? What is your pandas version? Can you give us a reproducible example?

Comment: yes it works in jupyter notebook, pandas 1.0.3

Answer (score 0):

apparently style.format use html and css support, and spyder doesn't support this, but jupyer notebook does, so I had to change the way to apply format to columns if I wanted to stay with spyder

```
#for one column
top100v3["DEPOSITOS"] = top100v3["DEPOSITOS"].apply(lambda x : "{:,.0f}".format(x))

#for many columns  
col_formatlist = ["DEPOSITOS", "COLOCACIONES"]

for col in col_formatlist:
top100v3[col] = top100v3[col].apply(lambda x: f'{x:,.0f}'.format(x))

top100v3["%PROV"] = top100v3["%PROV"].apply(lambda x: "{:.2%}".format(x))
```

for more formats check this https://mkaz.blog/code/python-string-format-cookbook/